# missing iOS simulators

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have installed 2 simulator versions in XCode (10.3 and 8.1).  However, from Visual Studio, I am not able to use the 8.1 simulator.

Using Xamarin iOS from Visual Studio in Windows how do I choose to debug using the 8.1 simulator installed on the Mac side?

Here are the available simulators I have in Visual Studio 2017...
[image]

I have XCode 8.3.3 installed and added the iOS 8.1 simulator...
[image]

Comment: I assume that you have tried closing VS and starting it again?

Comment: Yes, closed VS and XCode, and restarted both.  Same results.  Are the 8.1 emulators supposed to show up (I assume yes)?

Comment: Maybe your build target is iOS 10, and your IDE filtered out the iOS 8 simulators?
Or you could try this:
Close VS for Mac/Xamarin Studio; Open Xcode; Open a Test Project; Launch it on the simulator; Reopen VS for Mac/Xamarin Studio; See if it's there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure that your simulators are listed as devices inside xcode a guide to this can be found [here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/working-with/identifying-ios-devices-and-simulators/) That link relates to calabash testing, but disregard that, it's an apt guide for double checking that the simulators exist on the mac. The terminal check is especially worth while doing to make sure that the device simulators are infact available. (Infact it's THE best way to confirm fully that this isn't an issue with something on the Mac.)

In regards to visual studio, honestly as it pulls the list from the Mac, the only thing you can do is to restart your PC, and your Mac. There are occassions where this genuinely fixes an annoying nonsensical xamarin issue.

Comment: "make sure that your simulators are listed as devices" - on mine, the Devices tab is empty, but there are a bunch listed in the Simulators tab. Are you saying there's a way to get the Simulator devices listed in the Devices tab? I don't see anything from the referenced article about that.